# Spring Cloud Multiproject or Single Projects

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, continuous-delivery

Does anyone have experience with running Spring Cloud Micro Services in production?

I have about 10 micro services within one big Maven multi-project. This means that all the source code is under a single repo. The advantages are that it is easy to check out and manage the project in my IDE.

My concern is with CI as it means that the build server will need to figure out which services changed and deploy them respectively. Alternatively all the micro services will be deployed every time a change is committed.

I'm eyeing exploding the project into a source repo per micro service (my gut feel is that this is the correct approach). This way only the affected service is deployed.

My goal is to run every micro service as a container on Kubernetes.

Do you have any advise / tips / concerns that you can raise that might be an unwelcome surprise down the line?

Answer (score 0):

More important than separating codebase is to create a separate CI/CD pipeline per microservice (running its own unit and integration tests), and another pipeline to integrate all microservices and run end-to-end tests.

Since you plan to release your microservices as Docker containers, consider a Docker Registry for versioning and distribution of your images.

Here are some references that follow this idea: [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/cicd-for-containerised-microservices), [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/ci-cd)

Comment: Test cases? Isn't that what production is for? Thanks for you input @Fabio

Comment: @leonardseymore, thanks! Hope it helps and answers your question.